# How to enable speech api higher quota

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to implement Google Speech API in my own application. Google Speech API's daily quota is limited to only 50 per day. But i want to handle more than One hundred thousand speech request per day. How to implement this?

Once i click apply higher quota it will be saying you need permission    https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gaM0SH8QW01wkRvHLKgW3AGFzCovecmyR3wTCwKTVFQ/formrestricted. But i am logged into my own gmail account. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i have analyzed, there is no provision to request for increase in quota currently. May be you need consider alternative like Cloud Speech API. It is clearly documented in the official [chromium link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys). Hope it helps.